# Sizing a duct silencer for range hood

Tags: hvac

I want to add a duct silencer to a range hood. The hood is a 400 cfm. The duct size is 7 inches. That cannot be changed. The duct run is virtually straight and about 6 feet to a roof vent. I’ve found several companies online that sell duct silencers. Fantech, is one of them. The issue is that all the production silencers I’ve seen are sized for 8-inch duct. I know that I could use duct adapters to bridge the size difference. But, will adding the reducing adapters 7 inch to 8 inch and 8 to 7 inch respectively introduce more noise?  And defeat the purpose of the silencer?

Answer (score 0):

Make the adaptors with an included angle of about 6 degrees - this is to reduce the losses to a minimum.

Then all joints, bends need to be smooth or radiused - again helps with noise.

Then increasing the diameter reduces the velocity for the same flowrate - higher speed means more noise.